# I will no longer be moderating SF

Tags: discussion, moderators

A few months ago I took a break from moderating and participating in SF for [reasons](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9570/126632) mostly unrelated to today's post. I am not entirely 100% satisfied with the way that turned out, but I am cautiously optimistic that SO can recover from its mistakes and rebuild trust between it and the community. But that is not why I'm posting today.

Between then and now I was diagnosed with stage 4 colon and liver cancer. I have already had one surgery and there is more chemotherapy and surgery ahead of me.

As a result of all this, I am going to need to devote time to focusing on my recovery, however long it takes. I will not be able to return to moderating Server Fault at any time in the foreseeable future. I have already advised the community team to go ahead and remove my moderator access, and the diamond may be gone by the time you read this.

Since I first joined in 2012, I have found SF to be an amazing community with some of the smartest, most competent sysadmins on the planet. I am honored to have learned so much from you all and I have been glad that I could make my own small contributions.

Over the next few weeks, as time permits, I will gradually begin to return to reading and participating in the site as an ordinary contributor. I look forward to seeing you all again.

Comment: Oh mate, sorry to hear such bad news, that said if I can get through it I'm sure you can too.

Comment: Michael, I've learned a lot from your anwers and comments. What I'm doing right now is I'm taking all the hope I've got and pouring it into you.

Comment: Thank you for everything you've done for us here, both as a contributor and community guide.

Comment: I tip my cap to you my friend, you've helped me in so many ways with your help and guidance on more than just SF. Good luck to you and I hope you kick its @ss.

Comment: Thanks for everythings, I have no words, but my english is not the best too, but most of all I'am wishing you a speedy full recovery. Take care man

Comment: I'm so sorry to hear that. I wish you all the best.

Comment: I'm sad to hear this news. Michael, you take care of yourself and yours and that the results of your treatment brings you good news.

Comment: I am sorry to hear the news. I really appreciate everything you've done for the site and our community. I wish you well.

Comment: <3 from me and best wishes for a speedy recovery.

Comment: Much love and strength to you.

Comment: Judging from the frequency of your posts, you seem to have recovered by now. I hope I am not wrong. All the best from the other end of the world.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Michael,

I am truly saddened by your news but heartened that you are able to deliver it to us yourself. I hope that your continued treatment works, is not further complicated by the Covid-19 crisis and that you are returned to good health.

I've learned so much from your participation here at ServerFault, I hope to learn so much more.

Thanks and Good Luck

Iain

Comment: I hope one day to see you post another ride on Strava too.

Answer (score 11):

As one of the simple users, not even often here, let met thank you on our behalf.

Moderators do a ton of work for all of us, and almost all of it is done behind the scene, and they are rarely thanked for it.

Thank **you** for your work, help, and time commitment.

Have a good rest, focus on listening to your own body and emotional needs, get all the help you can (friends, family, medicine, hobbies to keep your mind busy and/or happy, etc), and have a great recovery.

And when you come back to post here or another Q&A site later on, it will surely be a great pleasure to see questions and/or answers by someone with your knowledge and experience.

*note*: Please delete this whole post if it isn't proper (I post it for Mickael's benefit, principaly, and other moderators as well for the first part, but in itself this "answer" do not add much value to the other answers... I don't know if it is proper to reply like this. Don't hesitate to delete this.)